# Удаление строки в таблице по нажатию кнопки

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ребята, хочу что бы соответствующая кнопка удаляла строку на которой находится, а получается так что первая кнопка удаляет все строки. и еще вопрос по поводу нумерации. корректно ли я сделала? и еще такая вещь: по ходу когда удалены все строки, то нумерация будет продолжатся, то есть по идеи строка должна быть первой, а она 12. как это исправить подскажите

```js
var counter = 1;
var table = document.querySelector('.table tbody');
buttonClick.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var t = document.getElementById('t');

  var row = t.insertRow();

  var target = e.target;
  if (target.tagName = 'button') {
    row.insertCell().innerHTML = counter;
    counter++;
  }
  row.insertCell().innerHTML = fild.value;

  row.insertCell().innerHTML = '<input type="button" value="DELETE" id="del"  />';

  var del = document.getElementById('del');
  //del.addEventListener('click', function(el){
  var str = document.querySelectorAll('#table tr');
  del.addEventListener('click', function(but) {
    var trq = this.parentNode.parentNode;
    t.deleteRow(trq.rowIndex);
  })
  fild.value = "";

})
```

```css
#fild {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

table {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

#firstLine {
  text-align: center;
}

tr td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#buttonClick {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<p>Name of employer</p>
<input type="text" id="fild"><br>
<button id="buttonClick">Result</button>
<div id="table">
  <table id="t">
    <tr id="firstLine">
      <td>№</td>
      <td>Name of employer</td>
      <td>Delete</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var counter = 1;
var table = document.querySelector('.table tbody');
buttonClick.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var t = document.getElementById('t');

  var row = t.insertRow();

  var target = e.target;
  if (target.tagName = 'button') {
    row.insertCell().innerHTML = counter;
    counter++;
  }
  row.insertCell().innerHTML = fild.value;

  row.insertCell().innerHTML = '<input type="button" value="DELETE" class="del"  />';

  var del = document.getElementsByClassName('del');
  //del.addEventListener('click', function(el){
  var str = document.querySelectorAll('#table tr');
  for (var i = 0; i < del.length; i++) {
    del[i].addEventListener('click', function(but) {
      var trq = this.parentNode.parentNode;
      trq.remove();
    });
  }

  fild.value = "";

})
```

```css
#fild {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

table {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

#firstLine {
  text-align: center;
}

tr td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#buttonClick {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<p>Name of employer</p>
<input type="text" id="fild"><br>
<button id="buttonClick">Result</button>
<div id="table">
  <table>


    <tr id="firstLine">
      <td>№</td>
      <td>Name of employer</td>
      <td>Delete</td>
    </tr>
    <tbody id="t">
    </tbody>

  </table>
</div>
```